# Implementing Config class containing Enum Map by PureConfig and Enumeratum

Tags: scala, config, pureconfig, enumeratum

I'm trying to read my config file into my case class whose one of attribute is a Map of Enumeratum key and Case Class value by using **pureconfig** and **pureconfig-enumeratum** libraries version **0.14.0** with scala 2.11.
When I change the Map key from Enumeratum key to String, it works, but it does not work with Enum key.

```
import enumeratum.EnumEntry.{Hyphencase}
import enumeratum._
import pureconfig.{ConfigSource}
import pureconfig.generic.auto._
import pureconfig.module.enumeratum._ 

object CheckPureConfig extends App {
      
      private val myConf = ConfigSource.default.loadOrThrow[SsystemConf]
      println(myConf)
    }
    
    case class SsystemConf(target: Map[Ssystem, MyConfig])
    case class MyConfig(path: Ssystem, link: String)
    
    sealed abstract class Ssystem(myField: String) extends EnumEntry with Hyphencase{
      def printit() = myField
    }
    object Ssystem extends Enum[Ssystem] {
      val values = findValues
    
      case object MyEnumA extends Ssystem("testFieldEnum1")
      case object MyEnumB extends Ssystem("testFieldEnum2")
    }
```

And this is my application.conf

```
target {
   my-enum-a= {
      path : "samplepath1"
      link : "samplehttp1"
    }
    my-enum-b = {
          path : "samplepath2"
          link : "samplehttp2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use [configurable converter](https://pureconfig.github.io/docs/configurable-converters.html) to tell pureconfig how to transform your enum to Map keys. You have [`genericMapReader`](https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig/blob/7e8b8052cda77a46a06a668b7f824a689664e43e/core/src/main/scala/pureconfig/configurable/package.scala#L56) for that:

```
implicit def enumMapReader[V: ConfigReader]: ConfigReader[Map[Ssystem, V]] =
  genericMapReader { name =>
    Ssystem.withNameOption(name)
      .fold[Either[String, Ssystem]](Left(s"$name is not enum"))(Right(_))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just building on @mateusz-kubuszok answer, this is what worked for me for version 0.17.6.

Here my map key enum class is called `TriggerSource`

```
implicit def enumMapReader[V: ConfigReader]: ConfigReader[Map[TriggerSource, V]] =
    genericMapReader[TriggerSource, V] { name =>
      TriggerSource.withNameOption(name) match {
        case Some(value) => Right(value)
        case None        => Left(CannotConvert(name, "TriggerSource", s"$name is not enum"))
      }
    }
```